# firefox frozen HTML5 video that will not downgrade to flash

Tags: javascript, firefox, mime, html5-video

I'm using the Video JS player to play a video. Everything is great excpet for in Firefox. I've read a lot about it's issues with HTML5 video and having the correct MIME type. When testing the Video JS player, it worked correctly with their sourced video, and not mine. Is this because my server doesn't support the MIME type, or is there a mistake in my code?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="780" height="520" autoplay="auto" loop="loop" poster="Images/home.jpg"> 
            <source src="Video/fernando.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' /> 
            <source src="Video/fernando.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' /> 
            <source src="Video/fernando.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' /> 
        <!-- Flash Fallback -->
            <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="780" height="520" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> 
                <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" /> 
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" /> 
                <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["Images/home.jpg", {"url": "Video/fernando.mp4","autoPlay":true,"autoBuffering":true, onBeforeFinish: function() { return false; }, wmode: 'opaque'}]}' /> 
                <img src="Images/home.jpg" width="780" height="520" alt="Poster Image" title="No video playback capabilities." /> 
            </object> 
        </video>
```

Javascript:

```
    VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady({
    controlsBelow: false, // Display control bar below video instead of in front of
    controlsHiding: true, // Hide controls when mouse is not over the video
    defaultVolume: 0.85, // Will be overridden by user's last volume if available
    flashVersion: 9, // Required flash version for fallback
    linksHiding: true // Hide download links when video is supported
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting these in your .htaccecss file

AddType video/mp4 .mp4

AddType video/ogg .ogv

AddType video/webm .webm